# How Do I Access Data From a Multi-Table Inheritance Definition?

Tags: django, django-models

Straight from the Django Docs....

```
from django.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Restaurant(Place):
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I can see the data in my database so I know it's working...but I can't figure out how to access the data.  In the past I have used Class Based Views...this is my first go at using a multi-table inheritance structure beyond class based views.

I have tried to do...

```
 def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("App:create_restaurant_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.object.place_ptr_id})
```

Here's my urls...

```
path("create_restaurant",views.CreateRestaurantView.as_view(), name='create_restaurant'),    
path("create_restaurant_detail/<pk>/",views.CreateRestaurantDetailView.as_view(), name='create_restaurant_detail'),
```

And my Views....

```
class CreateRestaurantView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Restaurant
    form_class = CreateRestaurantForm
    template_name = 'create_restaurant.html'   

    def get_success_url(self):
        return redirect('App:create_restaurant_detail', kwargs={'pk':self.object.place_ptr_id})  

class CreateRestaurantDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    model = Restaurant
    context_object_name = 'restaurant_detail'
    template_name = 'create_restaurant_detail.html'
```

But the url lookup keeps saying not found.

In the log...I see....

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'create_restaurant_detail' with keyword arguments '{'kwargs': {'pk': 12}}' not found. 1 pattern(s
) tried: ['LevelSet/App/create_restaurant_detail/1bad5cba\\-a087\\-4f0a\\-9c3b\\-65ac096c3e42/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']
```

I'm trying to figure out how to access the data in the table.  Thanks for any thoughts and help in advance.

Comment: Can you add the code and the url patterns for this view and the "App:create_restaurant_detail" view to your question?

Comment: @IainShelvington Thank you for the response.  I have added the view and urls...

Comment: The `CreateRestaurantView` view has `Place` as its model not `Restaurant`? I assume you're talking about `CreateRestaurantView.get_success_url` giving you issues?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes....Ive tried putting the get_success_url on both models....as I said the data is getting created...but the url keeps saying not found...I've tried to pass many different things to the kwargs....can't seem to figure out how to get it to see the id....

Comment: `get_success_url` should return the URL to redirect to not an actual redirect response, try changing `return redirect(...)` to `return reverse(...)`. If that doesn't work, can you add the full traceback to the question?

Comment: @IainShelvington I updated the description above.  I'm not getting a traceback...just the error code that I posted in the description above in the system log.  Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Can you try adding `int:` to the `pk` parameter in your url pattern? `path("create_restaurant_detail/< int :pk>/",views.CreateRestaurantDetailView.as_view(), name='create_restaurant_detail'),`. Not sure if the fact you are passing an int is affecting the reverse since the is to match a string

Comment: @IainShelvington I tried that.  I also that.  It now gives me...http://127.0.0.1:8000/App/undefined.  I've tried less complicated urls and I still keep getting the undefined error...

Comment: @IainShelvington  I have it working.  I misunderstood CreateView.  I had to include form_valid and post overrides.  I'm not sure this is technically the best approach but it is working at the moment...Any thoughts on how to improve my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
class CreateRestaurantView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Restaurant
    form_class = CreateRestaurantForm
    template_name = 'create_restaurant.html'

def form_valid(self, form):
    instance = form.save()
    return JsonResponse({ 'id': instance.pk, 'success_url': self.get_success_url() })

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if "cancel" in request.POST:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Main:main'))
    else:
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        restaurant_instance = form.save()
        self.object = restaurant_instance
        return self.form_valid(form)

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('Newapp:create_restaurant_detail', kwargs={ 'pk' : self.object.place_ptr_id })
```

My URL...

```
path("create_restaurant_detail/<int:pk>/",views.CreateRestaurantDetailView.as_view(), name='create_restaurant_detail'),
```

I misunderstood CreateView.  This code is working at the moment, but I'm not sure JsonResponse is the best answer for form_valid.  I couldn't figure out the proper alternative but my original problem has been solved.  Thanks to Iain for helping me work through it.